# Why am I getting 403 error accessing a specific website?

Tags: error-logging

Funny enough, but whenever I try to access a specific website ([iwriter.com](http://www.iwriter.com)) I can't access it and it shows "403 error", also it contains some message like "You do not have permission to access the webpage..." etc. I can't get it. everyday for almost 15hours, I can't access the site. and if I am lucky enough maybe I can access. so why is it happening and how can I avoid this problem? Strangely, I can access the site by [www.hidemyass.com](http://www.hidemyass.com) , but again I can't login from there. So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for this issue:

1. Your IP address could be blocked by the website, or it blocks a range of IP addresses which includes yours.
2. Your ISP, or another censoring body, could be blocking the website.

Edit: The website itself seems to be badly written or under testing/maintenance. I opened it and tried to click on the sign up link, and it gave me a 404 Not Found error.